# How to listen state changes in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the angular's $[watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) function equivalent in React.js?

I want to listen state changes and call a function like getSearchResults().

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.getSearchResults();
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I haven't used Angular, but reading the link above, it seems that you're trying to code for something that you don't need to handle. You make changes to state in your React component hierarchy (via this.setState()) and React will cause your component to be re-rendered (effectively 'listening' for changes).
If you want to 'listen' from another component in your hierarchy then you have two options:

1. Pass handlers down (via props) from a common parent and have them update the parent's state, causing the hierarchy below the parent to be re-rendered.
2. Alternatively, to avoid an explosion of handlers cascading down the hierarchy, you should look at the [flux pattern](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview), which moves your state into data stores and allows components to watch them for changes. The [Fluxxor plugin](http://fluxxor.com/) is very useful for managing this.

Comment: But what about when you need to fetch remote data that use (part of) the state as an url / a parameter?

Comment: @RnMss - look at redux and reducers (http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) and also reselect (https://github.com/reactjs/reselect).

Comment: Good catch.
Solving it with [redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index) is the right and correct approach, especially for large scale projects and multi-team development.

Comment: The question is not about React 'listening' and re-rendering the dom. The question is about how a user can listen for a change in state (for example if the state `count` changes from `20` to `21`) and run some code when it changes. `useEffect` does this in React hooks. Not sure what the mechanism was before React hooks, or if there was one.

Answer (score 377):

The following [lifecycle methods](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component) will be called when state changes. You can use the provided arguments and the current state to determine if something meaningful changed.

```
componentWillUpdate(object nextProps, object nextState)
componentDidUpdate(object prevProps, object prevState)
```

Comment: Was needing to trigger a method when a property in another component was updated (up one via callback, down one via prop), and adding `componentDidUpdate` in the component with the prop was the right prescription. Thanks for this.

Comment: I think this is the best way to guarantee notification of state changes, which is what the OP asked. But note that neither of these methods will fire after a state change if you veto the update in shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: `componentWillUpdate` is being deprecated: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

Comment: will `componentDidUpdate` not also fire when receiving new props, not necessarily just when state changes?

Comment: Can I double like this?

Comment: `componentWillUpdate` is deprecated.

Comment: I think using hooks should solve all the problems.

Answer (score 95):

In 2020 you can listen to state changes with the useEffect hook like this

```
export function MyComponent(props) {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState('initialState')

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(myState, '- Has changed')
    },[myState]) // <-- here put the parameter to listen, react will re-render component when your state will be changed
}
```

Comment: but how I can use it for the class components?

Comment: @YuriiSpace with the corresponding componentDidUpdate(), componentDidMount, etc. hooks..

Comment: This usage of `useEffect` itself always causes an additional render – is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Philzen if you pass a dependency array as the second parameter of `useEffect` (i.e [myState] in the example above) the component will only rerender if one of the variables in the dependency array has changed.

Answer (score 38):

Since React 16.8 in 2019 with [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) Hooks, following are now equivalent (in simple cases):

AngularJS:

```
$scope.name = 'misko'
$scope.$watch('name', getSearchResults)

<input ng-model="name" />
```

React:

```
const [name, setName] = useState('misko')
useEffect(getSearchResults, [name])

<input value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
```

Answer (score 31):

I think you should be using below Component Lifecycle as if you have an input property which on update needs to trigger your component update then this is the best place to do it as its will be called before render you even can do update component state to be reflected on the view.

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    likesIncreasing: nextProps.likeCount > this.props.likeCount
  });
}
```

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps has been deprecated: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score 14):

If you use hooks like `const [ name , setName ] = useState (' ')`, you can try the following:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      console.log('Listening: ', name);
    }, [name]);
```

Comment: is there any way to get old value in useEffect ?
suppose name was empty at first then i type I in it
then in useEffect I will get i but what if I want to get previous state any Idea

Answer (score 5):

Using useState with useEffect as described above is absolutely correct way. But if getSearchResults function returns subscription then useEffect should return a function which will be responsible for unsubscribing the subscription . Returned function from useEffect will run before each change to dependency(name in above case) and on component destroy

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while but for future reference: the method shouldComponentUpdate() can be used.

> An update can be caused by changes to props or state. These methods
>   are called in the following order when a component is being
>   re-rendered:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps() 
shouldComponentUpdate() 
render()
getSnapshotBeforeUpdate() 
componentDidUpdate()
```

ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: You'll have to return a boolean from `shouldComponentUpdate` so it might not be suitable for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to see which one in the dependencies changes. This is better than the pure `useEffect` in many cases.

```
// useWatch.js
import { useEffect, useMemo, useRef } from 'react';

export function useWatchStateChange(callback, dependencies) {
    const initialRefVal = useMemo(() => dependencies.map(() => null), []);
    const refs = useRef(initialRefVal);
    useEffect(() => {
        for(let [index, dep] of dependencies.entries()) {
            dep = typeof(dep) === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(dep) : dep;
            const ref = refs.current[index];
            if(ref !== dep) {
                callback(index, ref, dep);
                refs.current[index] = dep;
            }
        }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, dependencies);
}
```

And in my React component

```
// App.js
import { useWatchStateChange } from 'useWatch';
...
useWatchStateChange((depIndex, prevVal, currentVal) => {
  if(depIndex !== 1) { return } // only focus on dep2 changes
  doSomething("dep2 now changes", dep1+dep2+dep3);
}, [ dep1, dep2, dep3 ]);
```