# how to refresh react render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to update reactjs jsx when modifying the setState after every click. In the console.log it shows the most updated array, but in the view it would not be changed.

https://codeshare.io/5DNELl

Comment: Please post your code here, not behind an external link.

Comment: I think the question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26408784/6138595

Comment: Why not to finish react official intro? You shouldn't have such questions after it.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [ask], the question as is is not useful for anyone.

Comment: @frontend I understand you accepted my answer, but I came up with a better solution for you - check it out. If you need `newArray` for some reason please clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

̶L̶o̶o̶k̶s̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶`̶n̶e̶w̶A̶r̶r̶a̶y̶`̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶d̶e̶p̶e̶n̶d̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶`̶c̶a̶r̶d̶A̶r̶r̶a̶y̶`̶.

̶Y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶`̶s̶e̶t̶S̶t̶a̶t̶e̶`̶'̶s̶ ̶[c̶a̶l̶l̶b̶a̶c̶k̶](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) ̶t̶o̶ ̶u̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶b̶a̶s̶e̶d̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶e̶s̶t̶ ̶`̶c̶a̶r̶d̶A̶r̶r̶a̶y̶`̶.̶

**EDIT:** I was looking at your code again and I noticed that you are not doing anything with `newArray` in your render. You can simply sort your copied `cardArray`... which is in the render...

Here's a working example:

```js
class Game extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

        this.state = {
            memoryCards: ['mario', 'luigi', 'browser', 'peach', 'wario', 'toad', 'yoshi', 'bowser-junior', 'waluigi', 'diddy-kong-jr' ],
            cardArray: [],
            count: 0
        }
    }

        shuffleCard() {
            this.setState({
                cardArray: [...this.state.memoryCards, ...this.state.memoryCards].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
            })
        }

        checkCard(cardName, index) {
            const item = [{
                name: cardName,
                indexNumber: index,
                flipped: true
            }];

            console.log(item);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <button onClick={() => this.shuffleCard()}>Click</button>
                    {this.state.cardArray.map((items, index) => (
                        <li className="card" key={index} onClick={() => this.checkCard(items, index)}>{items}</li>
                    ))}
                </div>
            )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render((<Game/>), document.getElementById('testing'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="testing"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to write:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => this.shuffleCard()}>Click</button>
                {this.state.cardArray.map((items, index) => (
                    return (<li className="card" key={index} onClick={() => this.checkCard(items, index)}>{items}</li>)
                ))}
            </div>
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're not actually updating annything. You do

```
cardArray: [...memoryCards, ...memoryCards]
```

which just rewrites the array in the same way. What is your goal here?

Answer (score 0):

Update cardArray by copying and sorting memoryCards then setState.

```
shuffleCard() {
        let cardArray = [...this.state.memoryCards, ...this.state.memoryCards].sort(() => 
            0.5 - Math.random());
        this.setState({cardArray});
        console.log(cardArray);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You render cards from `this.state.cardArray` therefore you should update `this.state.cardArray` in `shuffleCard` function:

```
shuffleCard() {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    cardArray: [...this.state.memoryCards, ...this.state.memoryCards].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
  });
}
```