# How do I search for titles in Cloud Firestore using the SearchBar from react-native-elements?

Tags: firebase, react-native, search, google-cloud-firestore, full-text-search

I imported a SearchBar from react-native-elements and I want to be able to search my articles by title. So the field I should be able to pull and search from Cloud Firestore is called '`title`'. I'm not sure how to do that.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { AppleCard } from "react-native-apple-card-views";
import firebase from "../../Firebase";
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export default class Discover extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection("articles").where("publish", "==", true);
    this.unsubscribe = null;
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
      search: '',
    };
  }

  onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    const articles = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { title, subtitle, imageUrlPath } = doc.data();
      articles.push({
        key: doc.id,
        doc, // DocumentSnapshot
        title,
        subtitle,
        imageUrlPath,
      });
    });
    this.setState({
      articles,
    });
  };
  

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
  }

  updateSearch = (search) => {
    this.setState({ search });
  };


  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <AppleCard
            largeTitle={item.title}
            smallTitle=""
            footnoteText={item.subtitle}
            resizeMode="cover"
            source={{uri:item.imageUrlPath}}
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate("Content", {
                articlekey: `${JSON.stringify(item.key)}`,
              });
              
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { search } = this.state;
    return (
      <ScrollView>
      <SearchBar
        placeholder="Search here..."
        onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
        value={search}
        platform='ios'
      />
      <View style={styles.discover}>
        <FlatList data={this.state.articles} renderItem={this.renderItem} />
      </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  discover: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#FBFCFC",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  card: {
    padding: 15,
  },
});
```

Comment: Where's the problem? The queries aren't triggering when you update the text in search bar?

Comment: Exactly. I think it's because I'm missing the actual query. I think I need to add something to updateSearch or create a new function because it's missing the functionality of what to search for.

Comment: Maybe you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402534/how-to-listen-state-changes-in-react-js) and run the Firestore query

Comment: Hi, you can take a look at this post [How to search document(s) from a collection based on a Field in Firestore database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001098/how-to-search-documents-from-a-collection-based-on-a-field-in-firestore-databa)